# Bash: Use printf for comma seperated columns

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, printf, ps

I'm attempting to write output from `ps` into two comma-separated columns with custom headers which I can write to a csv file. The target format looks like:

```
Process ID,Command name
282,sort
280,ps
284,head
136,bash
283,awk
281,awk
```

Here's the command I've composed so far:

```
ps -o pid="Process ID" -o comm="Command name" | (read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort -k2 -r)
```

which produces the following output:

```
Process ID Command name
     23104 sort
     24756 ps
     24757 bash
     19320 bash
     23103 awk
```

I need to replace the whitespace characters in each line (except the first, which needs special processing) with commas. Is there a way to do said replacement in the `printf` command? Or am I approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ps -o pid,comm --no-headers | awk 'BEGIN{print "Process ID,Command name"}{$1=$1}1' OFS=,
```

---

You can use the `printf` `read` combo. However, in your code, the `printf` prints only the first line read by `read`. The rest is printed by `sort`. `while` loop is your friend here:

```
printf 'Process ID,Command name\n'
while read -r id cmd; do
    printf '%s,%s\n' "$id" "$cmd"
done < <(ps -o pid,comm --no-headers)
```

And to have the output of `ps` sorted, pipe it to `sort` like you did, or use the `--sort` option:

```
ps -o pid,comm --no-headers --sort -comm
```